# How do I calculate the price inside the HTML table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I already view the data from the database and filter the data. Right now, I want to do the calculation but I didn't find a way to do calculation inside the HTML itself. Here's my html coding. Should I do the javascript function here? or how? I confused on how to do the calculation based on the array of the table.

```
@extends('admin.layouts.app')

@section('content')

<style>
tfoot {
    background-color: #a8d1e3;
}
</style>

<script>
    {{$items->links()}}
    console.log("try");

</script>

<div class="container">

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="float-right">{{$items->links()}}</div>
            <h3>Total Sales</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form action="{{route('admin-insurance.filter')}}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                <label>Filter by date : </label>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input id="from" name="from" value="{{$from}}" placeholder="From" type="text"
                                class="form-control datepicker">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input id="to" name="to" value="{{$to}}" placeholder="To" type="text"
                                class="form-control datepicker">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control" name="insurance_id">
                                <option value=-1">ALL</option>
                                @foreach ($insurances as $item)
                                    <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control" name="exported">
                                    <option value="-1">ALL</option>
                                    <option value="1">CHECKED</option>
                                    <option value="2">UNCHECKED</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pr-5 pl-5">Search</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            @include('admin.layouts.notification')
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Policy No</th>
                            <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
                            {{-- <th scope="col">Region</th> --}}
                            <th scope="col">Package</th>
                            <th scope="col">Plan</th>
                            <th scope="col">Enroll Date</th>
                            <th scope="col">Departure</th>
                            <th scope="col">Return</th>
                            <th scope="col">Price</th>
                            <th scope="col">Exported</th>
                            <th scope="col"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php $count = 1; ?>
                        @foreach ($items as $item)

                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">{{$count++}}</th>
                            <td>{{$item->policy_no}}</td>
                            <td>{{$item->insurance->name}}</td>
                            {{-- <td>{{$item->region->name}}</td> --}}
                            <td>{{$item->insurance->name}}</td>
                            <td>{{$item->plan->name}}</td>
                            <td>{{$item->created_at}}</td>
                            <td>{{$item->depart_date}}</td>
                            <td>{{$item->return_date}}</td>
                            <td>RM {{number_format($item->amount,2)}}</td>
                            <td>
                                @if ($item->exported == 0)
                                <strong>NO</strong>
                                @else
                                <strong>YES</strong>
                                @endif
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <a class="btn btn-xs btn-success mb-1 btn-block text-white"
                                    href="/admin/insurance/product/sales/{{$item->id}}">View</a>
                            </td>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" card-footer">
                @csrf
                <label for="TotalSales" align="right">Total Sales: </label>
                <input id="TotalSales"><br>
            <div class="float-right">{{$items->links()}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class=" card-footer">
            <form action="{{route('admin-insurance.download')}}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                <input id="from1" value="{{$from}}" name="from1" type="hidden">
                <input id="to1" value="{{$to}}" name="to1" type="hidden">
                <input id="insurance_id" value="{{$insurance_id}}" name="insurance_id" type="hidden">
                <input id="exported" value="{{$exported}}" name="exported" type="hidden">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Export to CSV</button>
                <a href="/admin/insurance/product/mark-exported" class="btn btn-success">Mark as Exported</a>
                <a href="/admin/insurance/product/benefit" class="text-white btn btn-secondary">Generate Report</a>
            </form>
            <div class="float-right">{{$items->links()}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Here's the controller..

```
public function filterDate(Request $request)
    {
        $insurances = Insurance::all();
        $from = $request->from;
        $to = $request->to;
        $insurance_id = $request->insurance_id;
        $exported = $request->exported;
        $enrollments = InsuranceEnrollment::where('status', '=', 2)
            ->where("insurance_id", $insurance_id)
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->paginate(10);

        $items = array(
            'items' => $enrollments,
            'insurances' => $insurances,
            'insurance_id' => $insurance_id,
            'exported' => $exported,
            'from' => $from,
            'to' => $to
        );



        return view('admin.insurance.sales.home')->with($items);
    }
```

Comment: why don't you just calculate in controller action, and just render it.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the *sum* in a query. Using SUM function in select.

Eg:

```
 DB::raw("SUM(marks) as total_marks")
```